# Auto submit form before going to next page of form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a multi-page form that was created for me. All of the pages on the form have submit button that saves the data to a database, a previous button that goes to the previous page and a next button. The problem is that the data does not save if I click the previous or next links.

How can I set it up so that that submit button is automatically pressed before going to the previous or next page of the form?

```
<a class="form-buttons" href="<?php echo $prev_url;?>">Prev</a>
<div class="form-buttons-middle"><input type="submit" name="status" value="Save" /></div>
<a class="form-buttons" href="<?php echo $next_url;?>">Next</a>
```

I'm new to programming so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use three submit buttons and depending on which one was clicked you can run a certain code block..

I.e.

```
<input type="submit" name="status" value="Prev" />
<input type="submit" name="status" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" name="status" value="Next" />

<?php

 if(!empty($_REQUEST['status']) && $_REQUEST['status'] == 'Prev'){
      //save data and redirect to previous page using header();
 }

 if(!empty($_REQUEST['status']) && $_REQUEST['status'] == 'Next'){
      //save data and redirect to next page using header();
 }

 if(!empty($_REQUEST['status']) && $_REQUEST['status'] == 'Save'){
      //save data and do whatever you want
 }


?>
```